# Manage the reload of a component through another component located in a different route in REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having difficulties with my react application. I have a component that cyclically calls iframes, making them visible for a few seconds. The "reload" takes place via a button.
However, I need to check the iframe reload from another page. For example, create a "configuration.js" component in which there is a button which, once clicked, activates the "reload" function.
The iframe reload is however rendered in "http: // localhost: 3000 / simulatoretv", while the button that starts the reload is present in "http: // localhost: 3000 / configurator".
I hope I've been sufficiently clear. I attach the script of the component "Advertising", through which I run the reload of the iframes.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Pubblicità extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    iframeSrcs: ["/300x250", "/160x600", "/468x60"], 
    visibility: false
  };

  reload = () => {
    const iframeLength = this.state.iframeSrcs.length;
    if (this.state.index < iframeLength) {
      this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1,
        visibility: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true }); //starting again
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ visibility: false });
    }, 15000);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 500
          }}
          onClick={this.reload}
        >
          pubblicità
        </button>
        {this.state.visibility ? (
          <iframe
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              left: 500,
              right: 0,
              top: 10
            }}
            key={this.state.index}
            title="AdSlot"
            src={this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
            height="100%"
            width="100%"
            scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0"
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Pubblicità;
```

This is the other component, where I would like the controlled iframes to be shown by the "Pubblicità" component.
The route of this component is "http: // localhost: 3000 / platformOTT".

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SimulatoreTV from "./SimulatoreTV";
import Pubblicità from "./Pubblicità";

class PiattaformaOTT extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SimulatoreTV />
        <Pubblicità />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PiattaformaOTT;
```

Thanks to those who want to help me.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to trigger one function from remote functions. For this you need real-time websocket like connection. You need to establish a common connection between your sessions. for easy and quick implementation, you can use Firebase real-time storage and detect changes on a certain path and reload your iframe over it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer first of all.
How could I do this? Do you know any examples from which I can understand how to do it?

Comment: You can start reading docs at https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Instead of using firebase, do you think I could use socket.io?